# Prevent close event for node.js spawn when spawned process throws an error

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a nodejs server that starts a python script with `spawn`.

There are checks in the python script that can throw an error, and it's actually expected to have those error checks and returned to the server.

But when an error is thrown, the `close` event in node is eventually triggered and the nodejs server stops altogether.

I cannot seem to figure out how to prevent the spawned process from exiting and closing the server (just accepting and treating the error from the python script). Can someone guide me there?

Or should I maybe restart the server each time?

Answer (score 0):

`Nodejs` server is closing when an error is thrown in the `Python` script because it is waiting for the script to `exit`.

To prevent the `Nodejs` server from closing, you can use the `child_process.on('exit')` event to handle the error. In the event handler, you can catch the error and then do something with it.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const pythonChild = spawn('python3', ['your_script.py']);

pythonChild.on('exit', (code) => {
  if (code != 0) {
    console.error(`Error in Python script: ${code}`);
  }
});
```